# One to many relationship returns NULL

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following Migrations:

Table: bebidas:

```
class CreateBebidasTable extends Migration{

  public function up() {
    Schema::create('bebidas', function ($table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->integer('tipo_id')->unsigned();
      $table->string('bebi_name');
      $table->string('bebi_size');
      $table->float('bebi_price');
      $table->timestamps();
      $table->foreign('tipo_id')->references('id')->on('tipobebidas');
    });
  }

  public function down() {
    Schema::drop('bebidas');
  }

}
```

Table: tipobebidas

```
class CreateTiposBebidasTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tipobebidas', function($table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('tipobebidas');
    }

}
```

These are the models:

```
class Bebida extends Eloquent{

  public function TipoBebida() {
    return $this->belongsTo('TipoBebida');
  }

}


class TipoBebida extends Eloquent{

  protected $table = "tipobebidas";


  public function Bebidas() {
    return $this->hasMany('Bebida');
  }

}
```

Each `Bebida` (drink) has a `TipoBebida` (drink type) and vive-versa. I'm trying to get a composed table showing all fields from the `bebidas` table and `tipobebidas` table.

Based on Laravel's documentation on [eager loading](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading), I'm running the following command:

```
$bebidas = Bebida::with('tipobebida')->get();
```

At this point `$bebidas` has the following value:  (I'm removing the timestamps fields)

```
[
{"id":1,"bebi_name":"COCA-COLA","bebi_size":"1 litro",
 "bebi_price":4,"tipo_id":1,"tipobebida":null},
{"id":2,"bebi_name":"COCA ZERO","bebi_size":"1 litro",
 "bebi_price":4,"tipo_id":1,"tipobebida":null}
]
```

Instead of `"tipobebida":null`, I was expecting something like `"name":"refrigerantes"` or some representation of the `tipobebidas` table contents.

I inspected the SQL commands being run, here it is:

```
select * from `tipobebidas` where `tipobebidas`.`id` in (?)
```

How can I get this to work?

I'll be using this data on a couple nested `foreach` loops to show the drinks `Bebida` grouped by type `TipoBebida`.

Thank you!

Comment: Try using Tipobebida with capitalized first letter in the with() statement

Comment: Just tried it. Got the same result.

Comment: It may be null due to the eager loading. Try getting them without eager loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work. ***It all came down to naming conventions.***

Here's what I did:

-The name of the `foreign id field` must be the `singular` of the `table` name plus `_id`, therefore the migration for `bebidas` was changed to the following:

```
class CreateBebidasTable extends Migration{

  public function up() {
    Schema::create('bebidas', function ($table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->integer('tipobebida_id')->unsigned();  // ** new field name **
      $table->string('name');
      $table->string('size');
      $table->float('price');
      $table->timestamps();
    });
  }

  public function down() {
    Schema::drop('bebidas');
  }

}
```

Also, the foreign key relationship was producing a SQL error, tried to fix it, still nothing, so I **removed the following line:** `$table->foreign('tipo_id')->references('id')->on('tipobebidas');`

Everything else remained unaltered.

The eager loading is working.

Thanks everyone for your help!!!

Comment: What if you're using a string for the ID and not an integer?

Answer (score 0):

First, in tables bebidas and tipobebidas I don't see and foreign keys...
I think in bebidas you should have tipobebidas_id and it is a foreign key to tipobebidas id field.
After you do that, change your model methods to:

```
class Bebida extends Eloquent{
  protected $table = "bebidas";

  public function TipoBebida() {
    return $this->belongsTo('TipoBebida', 'tipobebida_id');
  }

}

class TipoBebida extends Eloquent{

  protected $table = "tipobebidas";

  public function Bebidas() {
    return $this->hasMany('Bebida');
  }
```

Comment: I had a second migration that added the foreign key to table `bebidas`. Consolidated it on the same file now.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The table already had the foreign key on my system. I had forgotten to consolidate all the migrations on a single file before posting the question here (a sign of burn-out I guess). Thank you!

Comment: I found the solution. It came down to simple naming conventions. THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP. I tried publishing the solution, but, I'll have to wait several hours because I'm a new user.